# JSONModel library / model collection wrong

Tags: ios, json, wordpress, jsonmodel

I'm using JSONMODEl (https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) to parse a wordpress JSON FEED (with json-api).

Everything go's well except if I want the "comments".

my feed is like that :

```
comments =             (
                                {
                    content = "<p>My comment</p>\n";
                    date = "2014-08-29 20:56:29";
                    id = 97813;
                    name = johndoe;
                    parent = 0;
                    url = "http://www.google.com";
                }
            );
```

so I try to make my "newsmodel" like that :

```
    #import "JSONModel.h"
    #import "commentmodel.h"

@protocol NewsModel @end


@interface NewsModel : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* content;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* thumbnail_images;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* premium;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CommentModel* comments;
@end
```

and my commentmodel like that

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
@interface CommentModel : JSONModel

@property (assign, nonatomic) int id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString* content;
@end
```

But When I try to build my app, my "feed" is empty.

if I comment the "comment" part of the news model, I got the content....

I think I'm stuck somewhere, but where ! If someone ave an idea :)

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comments` is an array, not a single comment, notice the top level `(` and `)` which designate an array in a `NSDictionary` `NSLog()`. Inside of the is an array element designated by `{` and `}`.

But the `NewsModel` has `comments` defined as a single comment (`CommentModel`), not an array. it should probably be declared:

In the docs see [Model collections](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel#model-collections) and how `products` is handled.

You will have to declare a `protocol`, see the example `protocol` at the top of the "Model collections" examples.

```
@protocol CommentModel
@end
```

Above:

```
@interface CommentModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray< CommentModel >* comments;
```

Comment: I try, but i have a " Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NewsModel'" error...
And in the doc, there insn't any protocol for the orderModel.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
@protocol CommentModel
@end

@interface CommentModel : JSONModel
@property (assign, nonatomic) int id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSString* content;
@end

@interface NewsModel : JSONModel
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* content;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* thumbnail_images;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* premium;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* id; //int?
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<CommentModel>* comments;
@end
```

Comment: `id` could be a string, `NSLog()` of `NSDictionaly` does not enclose all strings in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, got it to build, but now If i try to alloc it with

```
@try {
        _feed = [[NewsFeed alloc] initWithDictionary:obj error:nil];

    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"Parse error : %@ reason %@", [e name], [e reason]);
    }
```

I got a Bad property protocol declaration reason  is not allowed JSONModel property protocol, and not a JSONModel class.

my news feed is like that

```
@interface NewsFeed : JSONModel
@property (nonatomic, strong)   NSArray <NewsModel> *posts;
@end
```

And work like a charme without the "comment" part...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answers above, since I can't add a comment yet, all you have to do, is add an empty protocol with the same name, like this:

```
@protocol CommentModel
@end
```

Then, as noted here [JsonModel documentation](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel#model-collections),  notation would be different than a  notation. The first one is a protocol declaration needed for JsonModel to work, the other one is an objc compiler helper declaration. You can combine them as noted in the same example:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray<ProductModel *> <ProductModel> *products;
```